# Motherboard for the Intel i3 2100

Tags: motherboard, intel-graphics, intel-core-i3

This might be trivial to some, but I am lost.

The `Intel i3 2100` cpu has Intel HD graphics integrated.

How do I choose motherboard to use this feature?

If the motherboard doesn't have integrated another graphics chip, then there would be no way to use it, since there is no adapter for the cable.
But if it has, it would be wasted money because the modo's chip would never be used.

I'm repeating myself: This might be trivial to some but I am lost!

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/296192-12-intel-motherboard-dh67vr-2100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a motherboard with an LGA1155 and it should list that it supports a Core i3.

The board will have video ports on the back (VGA, DVI, or HDMI) but doesn't have it's own graphics chip.  The video ports are linked to the CPU socket and will use the Core i3's graphics.

Comment: I am aware of the 1155 and the i3. My question is if there are motherboards in the market that have Video Output (hdmi, dvi) without integrated graphics card.